# Extracting data of recent n active days of every user from dataframe of gaming activity

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime, window-functions, pandasql

So, first of all, data looks like this :

[image]

[Sample Data if you would like to work](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qpi-x36UHSTWUNEzTotVqDPfbY5KWtq0/view?usp=sharing)

Every record in the table represents a specific user playing a specific type of game with some amount of money. So, it is possible that a user might play one day and not the other day.

What I would like to extract is ...activity of users in their last active n days(let's say n is 15). To be clear, I'll take an example: Let's say a user with account_id 12345 has played some games on Sep 16,17,18,19,25,26 2020, and on Oct 8 2020(no of the games he played doesn't matter, he has played at least one game on those days ). What I had done till now is I've extracted the activity of that player from the recent date he played(Oct 8 2020 to 15 days back, i.e, 24 Sep 2020). So, I'll only have the gaming activity of the player on 25,26 Sep 2020, and Oct 8 2020. But what I want is the activity of the past 15 active days which includes Oct 8 2020 and Sep 16,17,18,19,25,26 and 8 active days before that(since I want 15 days and the dates I've mentioned count to 7)

My approach for the activity of the last 15 days(I might be active or Inactive) is

```
WITH BASE AS( 
SELECT 
MAX(date) AS LastDate, 
account_id 
FROM aug 
GROUP BY account_id
) 
SELECT 
ga.account_id, 
ga.date
FROM aug GA 
JOIN BASE B ON b.account_id = ga.account_id 
WHERE ga.date >= DATE_SUB(b.LastDate, INTERVAL 15 DAY) 
  AND ga.date <= b.LastDate
```

I'm unable to convert these last 15 days into the last active 15 days. Pls, guide me on this.
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: @forpas It's okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for joins.
You have all the data you need in the table `aug`.
Use `DENSE_RANK()` window function to select the rows for the last 15 active days:

```
select account_id, date, Real_money, table_name
from (
  select *, dense_rank() over (order by date desc) dr
  from aug 
  where account_id = ?
) t
where dr <= 15
```

Replace `?` with the `account_id` that you want to search for.

If you want results for all the `account_id`s:

```
select account_id, date, Real_money, table_name
from (
  select *, dense_rank() over (partition by account_id order by date desc) dr
  from aug 
) t
where dr <= 15
```

For versions of SQLite prior to 3.25.0, without window functions, create this index:

```
CREATE INDEX aug_account_id_date ON aug(account_id, date);
```

and try:

```
select a.* from aug a
where a.date >= coalesce(
  (
    select distinct date 
    from aug
    where account_id = a.account_id
    order by date desc limit 14, 1
  ), '0000-00-00'
)
```

or:

```
select a.* from aug a
where (select count(distinct date) from aug where account_id = a.account_id and date >= a.date) <= 15
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=2fee0edbaebbd097824fb8d498225c79).

Comment: Hi @forpas...I need the same thing for all the unique account_id's existing in the data

Comment: @Forpas....it is saying syntax error ...not sure why (PandaSQLException: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "(": syntax error
[SQL: select account_id, date, Real_money, table_name from ( select *, dense_rank() over (partition by account_id order by date desc) dr  from aug ) t where dr <= 15])

Comment: @DroningHangman If you are using SQLite, why did you tag MySql? In any case the code works fine in SQLite too: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=111b30c284baf1ee410c8df1e285b4a5

Comment: @Forpass, sorry for that, I've changed the tag to pandasql once Gordon answered. I understood the query you wrote but don't know why I'm getting syntax error. Pls let me know if you can figure it :  test_q = psql.sqldf("select account_id, date, Real_money, table_name from ( select *, dense_rank() over (partition by account_id order by date desc) dr  from aug )  where dr <= 15")

Comment: Execute this query: `select sqlite_version();` to get the version of SQLite that you are using.

Comment: sqlite_version is 3.22.0

Comment: Window functions in SQLite are supported from version 3.25.0, this is why you get the syntax error. I will post a new query without window functions, but it will be far less efficient if your table is as large as the csv.

Comment: See the last query in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts @Fropas, everything's working good now and I've learnt a lot from this discussion. Thanks to you :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly:

```
SELECT gab.*
FROM (SELECT ga.account_id, ga.date,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY b.LastDate DESC) as seqnum
      FROM aug GA JOIN
           BASE b
           ON b.account_id = ga.account_id 
     ) gab
WHERE seqnum >= 15;
```

Comment: Hi @Gordon, Thanks for your effort. Can you pls explain how this works and also will this work in sqlite3. Basically I'm working in jupyter notebook and I'm using pandasql library and I'm getting syntax error when I do this :: test = psql.sqldf("WITH BASE AS( SELECT  MAX(date) AS LastDate, account_id  FROM aug  GROUP BY account_id) SELECT gab.* FROM (SELECT aug.account_id, aug.date, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY b.LastDate DESC) as seqnum FROM aug GA JOIN BASE b ON b.account_id = ga.account_id ) gab WHERE seqnum >= 15 ")

Comment: @DroningHangman Set the correct tag for your question. Is this SQLite or MySql? Your code is for MySql.